I brutally abused my one-year-old kitten for two days. I have no good excuse. Will he forgive me now? I feel so guilty now
I brutally abused my one-year-old kitten for two days. I have no good excuse. If I could go back in time and stop myself, I would, but I can't. I have to live with it and get better. Will he forgive me now? I feel so guilty now, what can I do to stop being his enemy?

seek a new caregiver for that kitten and never get a pet again. Problem solved for catkind.
